# Swagger add version to resource in rest api path

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jersey, swagger

I would like to have swagger generating me an api path like this:

```
.../v1/resource1
.../v1/resource2

.../v2/resource1
.../v2/resource2
```

In the mustache file, there is a tag:

```
@Path("/{{baseName}}")
```

But it seems like to end up with the same name as the current resource.

A full version of the api.mustache is found here:
https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/tree/master/modules/swagger-codegen/src/main/resources/JavaJaxRS/jersey1_18

Can someone help?

Comment: Shouldn't the Swagger path be the same you set in your web.xml? That way, you have clickable links in Swagger. I use `<url-pattern>/v1/*</url-pattern>` in my jersey servlet mapping and that's what Swagger gives me as well.

Comment: I dont use a web.xml file. I do everything programmatically. I will check my context.addServlet part